# android eclipse resource image not found in drawable

Tags: android, eclipse, drawable

error:  No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/mydroidbg.png').

here's the location of my image: C:\Users\Rogeross\Documents\ECLIPSE\MyFirstApp\res\drawable-hdpi\mydroidbg.png

here's the main.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@drawable/mydroidbg.png"  //error here
>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TOTO ANDROID" 
    android:gravity="center"
    />

 <Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="PRESS ME!!"
    android:textSize="19dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
     />

    </LinearLayout>
```

i already cleaned, refreshed my project but it still cannot see my image file... please help....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not mention the file extension. Use:

```
android:background="@drawable/mydroidbg"
```

Comment: thanks man... i did earlier but did not work... wonder why it worked now... anyway... thanks again!

Comment: @Roj if the answer solved your problem, you should accept it by clicking the tick mark beside it.